# How to create pointer to c++ vector element?

Tags: c++

I have a global static `std::vector<Type>`, and a struct which will hopefully select from one of the elements.

```
typedef struct
{
    bool initial
    bool opening;
    std::string friendly_name;
} Type;

using TypeVec = std::vector<Type>;
static const TypeVec starting_types
{
    { true, true, "Open" },
    { true, false, "Close" },
    ...
};

typedef struct
{
    Type type;
} SessionInfo;
```

Now the SessionInfo struct will choose one of the types in the starting_types. If I write

```
SessionInfo session;
session->type = starting_types.at (0);
```

This will create a copy of the first element.  I want to do the equivalent of `auto&` thus:

```
auto& type = starting_types.at (0);
```

But don't know how to save it into `SessionInfo::type`.

Comment: Make `Type type;` in `SessionInfo` a reference or a pointer, otherwise it will always be a copy. Also there's no need to do `typedef struct {...} Name;` in C++, just write `struct Name {...};`.

Comment: Not related to your question, but `starting_types` being `const` indicates, that the number of elements stored in `starting_types` is known at compile time. So you probably want to use `std::array<Type, numOfTypes>` instead. You might also want to look at [Difference between 'struct' and 'typedef struct' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c)

Comment: Since the vector is `const`, you can only obtain a `const` reference to an element.  For example, `const auto &type = *starting_types.begin()` to obtain a reference to the first element.   To obtain a reference to an element with index `i`, do `const auto &type = *(starting_types.begin() + i)`.     Bear in mind this ASSUMES that the vector is not empty (as is the case in your code) AND that `i` is a valid index (i.e. `i` is between `0` and `starting_types.size()-1` inclusive).   If either assumption is invalid, the behaviour is undefined.